# Access cross domain nested iframe from within the main iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a page that has a cross-domain iframe.  On the page loaded in the iframe is a print button that runs some javascript to print an iframe named printFrame sitting on the page (on the nested page, not on the parent page).  When I click on the button, in FF it works but IE gives me an error: frames.printFrame is null or not an object.  I'm confused.  The code is not trying to access the parent document, why isn't it working?

The code crashes on line 9 of iframedoc.html, when I try to access the printframe

Parent document HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://www.otherdomain.com/iframeDoc.html"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

iframedoc.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function printContent(){
    frames['printFrame'].focus();
    var printFrameDiv = frames['printFrame'].document.getElementById("printDiv");
    printFrameDiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById('printableContent').innerHTML;
    frames['printFrame'].print();
    window.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="printFrame" name="printFrame" src="/printFrame.html"></iframe>

<div id="mainContent">
    <div id="printableContent">
        My printable content is here
    </div>
    <div id="nonPrintableContent">
        Content that I dont want to print is here
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="printContent()">Print</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried a debugger to see what the document title etc are to make sure you are where you think you are?

Comment: Could you give us more information, like a sample of the HTML that is rendered by the browser. This will make it easier for us to duplicate/answer your question